# What is the formal definition of LR grammar and how to prove it is not ambiguous?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

Hi from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR-attributed_grammar) it said that LR grammar is type of grammar can be evaluated by LR parsing.

On dragon book, it says:

> A grammar for which we can construct a parsing table using one of
> the methods in this section and the next is said to be an LR grammar.

Both of them are not mathematical definition and hard to describe precisely.

Furthermore, if I define:

$$
s\to AB\\
A\to abc|ab\\
B\to cd|d\\
$$

And set handle of $abcd$ as $ab$, it is obvious that the only sentence will be accepted by LR parser and the grammar is ambiguous.

Thus may I ask a formal (more like mathematical) definition of LR grammar, and prove that it is not ambiguous??

Thanks a lot!